# How do i redirect any transaction entering my wallet to the parent wallet

Tags: transactions, etherscan, private-key, wallet-transfer, erasure-codes

My wallet private key has been conpromised and anytime I receive any eth transaction it automatically redirect to the Hacker wallet address almost immediately I'm so confused right now I need all the help I can get cause that's my business wallet address please

Answer (score 0):

Usually that behavior indicates the private key has been compromised. Unfortunately there is nothing that can be done about the leaked address, create a new account, perhaps use a hardware wallet.

Comment: Hey @Ismael, sorry for off-topic but I wanted to ask you a followup on a [deleted thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JCz613IcfSUJ:https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98001/upon-deploying-this-token-name-and-symbol-are-not-visible-any-ideas-why-bsc&client=firefox-b-d&hl=sk&gl=sk&strip=0&vwsrc=0) from 2 days ago. You mentioned that [this](https://bscscan.com/address/0x369Eb6Cc7d0c07F66316558Eeb2982204Af01F39#code) contract has deployed the `Address` library. How can you tell? I thought the constructors would be called when the contract is deployed.

Comment: @dvdblk Because `Address` is the name of the verified contract, `Address` is a library and the very short bytecode make it unlikely it to be a contract, so it fits with being a library. If you are the developer make sure you keep a reference where each contracts was deployed, truffle print addresses where each contract was deployed, other tools should have similar output. If you have more doubts it is better to create a new question.